# SSRS export to excel placing hyperlink on entire cell

Tags: excel, reporting-services

I have two expressions placeholders within a cell in my report.  One placeholder contains an Action with a hyperlink, whereas the other expression does not have a hyperlink Action.  When I run the report, the hyperlink only works when the mouse is clicked on the fist expression, which is exactly what I want it to do.  However when I export the report to Excel, the hyperlink works when I click anywhere in the cell,  including the second expression. This is not desirable.  Is there something I am doing wrong in the report that would cause this?  I just want to navigate to the URL when someone clicks on the expression, not on the entire cell.

Comment: I believe the problem is due to the limitation of Excel not allowing partial text hyperlink within cells. You could try to split your placeholders to different cells so when they are exported, they are in different cells.

Comment: I can't really do what I want with different cells.  I want the two expressions to appear one after the other without spacing gaps, and they are variable length.  Excel handles hyperlinks in a very annoying way.  It would make things a bit better if it used Ctrl-Click instead of immediately navigating to the link when you click on the cell.